# javascript array - what is true expression?

Tags: javascript, arrays

create 3 undefined, empty array.

```
var a1 = [,,,];
var a2 = new Array(3);
```

from JavaScript: The Definitive Guide,

```
0 in a1 //true
0 in a2 //false
```

but, in real world browser, getting different result. (IE8 and chrome 33...)

```
0 in a1 //false
0 in a2 //false
```

which is true, book or real world?

Comment: Looks like the book is wrong. As you can see from the spec, http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.4, `[,,,]` does not add any values to the array.

Comment: @user2864740: No, `[,,,]` is **not**`[undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]`.

Comment: @FelixKling it is undefined

Comment: that book is at least 2 years old the specification of how arrays work probably changed since that was printed.

Comment: @MinaGabriel: Accessing a non-existing property *returns* undefined, but it's not the same has adding `undefined` to the array. Just try `0 in [,]` and `0 in [undefined]`.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: ECMAScript5 also exists a couple of years already and that behavior was already defined in ECMAScript3.

Comment: @MinaGabriel—elided members of Arrays don't exist. `'1' in [0,,1]` returns false.

Comment: Which edition of the _The Definitive Guide_ are you reading?

Comment: @BlackSheep 5th and 6th edition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the book is wrong. As you can see from the [specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.4), `[,,,]` does not add any values to the array:

> The production *ArrayLiteral : [ Elision<sub>opt</sub> ]* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *array* be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression new Array() where *Array* is the standard built-in constructor with that name.
> 2. Let *pad* be the result of evaluating *Elision*; if not present, use the numeric value zero.
> 3. Call the `[[Put]]` internal method of array with arguments "length", pad, and false.
> 4. Return array.

*("Elisions" are the `,` which are not preceded or followed by an expression.)*

In simpler terms:

- Create an empty array
- Evaluate the `,`, which is basically just counting them, starting from 1. 
  So `,,,` results in 3.
- Then set the `length` of the array to the result (e.g. 3).

And that's exactly what `new Array(3)` is doing as well.

---

There is also a less formal description of elided elements:

> Array elements may be elided at the beginning, middle or end of the element list. Whenever a comma in the element list is not preceded by an AssignmentExpression (i.e., a comma at the beginning or after another comma), the missing array element contributes to the length of the Array and increases the index of subsequent elements. Elided array elements are not defined. If an element is elided at the end of an array, that element does not contribute to the length of the Array.

Comment: @user2864740: That's what I linked to.

Comment: Near the top: ".. the missing [aka elided] array element contributes to the length of the Array and increases the index of subsequent elements. Elided array elements are *not* defined."

Answer (score 2):

The Array constructor (`new Array( 3 )`) does set the `length` attribute to 3 but does not create any members of the array – not even undefined values.

> In cases when there is only one argument passed to the Array constructor and when that argument is a Number, the constructor will return a new sparse array with the length property set to the value of the argument. It should be noted that only the length property of the new array will be set this way; the actual indexes of the array will not be initialized.

Source: http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#array.constructor

Testing that in Chromium does indeed result in two false values…

The `in` operator returns false if the given key does not exist:

```
var a1 = [1,,3,4];

0 in a1 // true
1 in a1 // false
```